# items of the list lost after navigation in windows phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application, I have list that have all contacts like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        List<CustomContact> listOfContact = new List<CustomContact>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
    private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contacts cons = new Contacts();
        cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

        cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
    }

    void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        listOfContact.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (var c in e.Results)
            {
                CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();
                contact.Name = c.DisplayName;
                int count = c.PhoneNumbers.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (count > 0 && c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber) )
                    {
                        contact.Number[i]= c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();//.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        contact.Number[i] = "";
                    }
                }
                listOfContact.Add(contact);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfContact.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(listOfContact1.Count != listOfContact.Count)
                {
                    listOfContact1.Add(listOfContact.ElementAt(i));
                }

            }
                ContactResultsData.ItemsSource = listOfContact;


        }

        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            //No results
        }
        if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
        }
        else
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
        }
    }

        private void hyplnk_Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Contact"] = listOfContact;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/createGroups.xaml?Contact=" + listOfContact, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

below is the `CustomContact` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public class  CustomContact
    {
        public string[] number = new string[5];
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string[] Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set { number = value; }
        }

        public CustomContact()
        {
        }

        public CustomContact( Contact contact)
        {
            Name = contact.DisplayName;
            int count = contact.PhoneNumbers.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (count > 0 && contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber))
                {
                    Number[i] = contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   Number[i] = "";
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

below is XAML page

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10">

        <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <ListBox x:Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="293" Margin="24,0,0,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Button x:Name="ButtonContacts"
            Content="Get All Contacts"
            FontSize="15"
            Width="200"
            Height="70"
            Background="AliceBlue"
            Foreground="Blue"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Click="ButtonContacts_Click" Margin="27,30,0,322"></Button>
</Grid>
```

And in the `hyplnk_Next_Click` event, I navigate list to the next page but when I come back to the previous page the items of list are lost and the list is empty. what should I do to maintain the list of elements after navigation. Kindly suggest me.
Waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you load the contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already save the transientState (the CustomContancts list), although your hyperlinkbutton handler is not the place to do it. I presume you're not loading it after you navigate back to the page with the contacts.

You should read and understand the [Application Execution Model](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx). It is crucial in Windows Phone development.

The place to save and load your page's state are the page's overriden methods OnNavigatedFrom OnNavigatedTo.

Here's an example

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{    
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Contains["Contact"])
    {
        listOfContact = 
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Contact"] as List<CustomContact>();
    }
}



protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Contact"] = listOfContact;
}
```

OnNavigatedFrom is called whenever you navigate away from a page and OnNavigatedTo is called when you navigate to a page.